# Can't unlock linux user account

Tags: linux, passwords, user-accounts, opensuse

I've got a Linux box (OpenSuSE 11.3) with a locked-out user account. I logged in as the root account to unlock it with `passwd -u <user>`, but I get a message `'Cannot unlock the password for <user>!'`

I tried changing the password to something new via `passwd`, but attempting to log in with this new password still gives the 'account has been locked due to x failed attempts' error message.

`passwd -S` gives status flags of 'PS' for the account. I don't recognise 'S', but at any rate it's not showing either 'L' (locked) or 'NP' (no password).  `/etc/shadow` doesn't contain any weird characters like `!` at the front of the line for this account. Looking at it in this distro's management app (YaST) appears to show that it *isn't* locked (the 'disable account' button is unchecked).

Where else do I need to check to see how and why this account is refusing to unlock/login?

Comment: Which distribution and version?

Comment: This machine is OpenSuSE 11.3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this issue today.
This was the fix.

pam_tally --user= --reset

Example

```
pam_tally --user=cyberninja --reset
```

I hope this helps someone.

---

I found this post looking for an answer to this exact question. I had the same error but on a SLES 11 SP2 server. My co-worker reset my password and tried to unlock my account with the command `passwd -u`. One of my other co-workers said I needed clear account in PAM and gave me the command. Which I have posted above.

---

Update,

I now have a fix that keeps this from happening again. It seems that there are two PAM files that where in conflict. These files are; `/etc/pam.d/login` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Both files have this line.

> auth    required   pam_tally.so    onerr=fail deny=3

You must commit out, this line from one of the files listed above. We commented the line out in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file.

After you do this you should never have this issue again.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Try to explain a bit more about how you got your problem and a also little bit more about your answer if you can.

Comment: Ok Sickest,I will update my post.

Comment: Worked in my RHEL6 server too. the command was 'pam_tally2' however.

Comment: Check the PAM config! In my PAM, it used file `/var/log/failllog`, but `pam_tally2` command by default uses `/var/log/tallylog`, so reported user as not locked. You can use `pam_tally2 --file /var/log/faillog`.

Comment: Thank you all. This helped me on our old Alcatel OXE PBX as the mtcl users has been locked for unknown reasons and therefore I was unable to log in via Telnet. I'm just leaving this moment here to improve some google search results and (maybe) help other people. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

I have been facing the same issue today with one user account in a server running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2, even after resetting the password and changing the age to 0 (chage -d 0 userID)

```
[me@mordor ~]$ ssh frodo@mordor

Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).


Account locked due to 29 failed logins
Password:
Account locked due to 30 failed logins
Password:
```

With the same escenario described by @Jam in his original post. Nothing showing the account locked neither on "/etc/passwd" nor on "/etc/shadow". Commands such as "passwd -S -a | grep frodo" shown that the ID was not locked (LK)

```
me@mordor:~> sudo passwd -S -a | grep frodo
frodo PS 01/01/1970 1 90 7 180
```

Also "**pam_tally2**" show that the ID was NOT locked:

```
me@mordor:~> sudo /sbin/pam_tally2 --user frodo
Login           Failures Latest failure     From
frodo             0
```

But the problem was in fact with "**pam_tally**"

```
me@mordor:~> sudo /sbin/pam_tally --user frodo
User frodo    (500)   has 32
```

After unlocking the userID password, I was able to login with the new credentials and avoid the error message.

```
me@mordor:~> sudo /sbin/pam_tally --user frodo --reset
User frodo    (500)   had 32
me@mordor:~> sudo /sbin/pam_tally --user frodo
User frodo    (500)   has 0
```

Hope this helps someone else to avoid breaking his/her head as I did in the last hour or so... So to make a long story short be aware to check both "**pam_tally**" and "**pam_tally2**" when the account is locked in SuSE!!

Regards,
Hernan.

Comment: Thanks so much:)  What's the difference between pam_tally and pam_tally2?

Comment: Check the PAM config! In my PAM, it used file `/var/log/failllog`, but `pam_tally2` command by default uses `/var/log/tallylog`, so wrongly reported user as not locked. You can use `pam_tally2 --file /var/log/faillog`.

Answer (score 5):

You can type:

```
pam_tally2 -r -u user_name
```

to unlock the account.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
usermod --expire 9999
```

to disable inactivity for the account (this sets the expire date to 1/1/9999). `passwd -u` only works if the password is "locked", but not for disabled accounts.

Comment: I see, so there is a difference between the password being locked/disabled and the account being locked/disabled? The message on failed login misled me then. Will this method affect the password expiry date, or is 'account expiry' a separate thing?

Comment: I tried this and now when I attempt to log in it just says 'login failed' even though I am definitely getting the password correct (after 1 failure I changed it to be 100% sure of this). Any suggestions? S:

Comment: This will change the account expiration, which is separate from the password expiration. So accounts may be active or expired, passwords may be active, locked, or expired, and it's possible to automatically expire an account after the password expires. What is the output of `passwd --status <username>` ? It would be helpful if you could add that to your question.

Comment: The version of `passwd` on this distro doesn't accept `--status` as an option but `passwd -S <user>` ('show password attributes') gives: `<user>    PS    <date>    <password expiry options>` where date is the date I last changed the password (yesterday), and password expiry options are `min age` (0), `max age` (90), `days before expiry to issue warning` (7), and `days after expiry with usable login` (-1). These settings all worked before, so I don't think any of them are the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could also have been that the account was just created and no password was assigned yet.

If so, `passwd -S <user>` will show `LK` (for locked) and `passwd -u <user>` will not work.

You just need to assign a passwd to the user to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With this command, you can create an unlocked user without any password:

```
adduser --gecos "Username" --disabled-password "username"
```

This means no random password hanging on the system.